# VueJs insert into nested list

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to let the user create the structure of my website. For example, I have buildings and rooms. The user must be able to create a building and subsequently insert rooms into it. However, what I tried to do seems not to achieve it:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alex_goranov/c4ssjqk0/) of what I have done so far.

js

```
new Vue({
  el: '#vue-app',

  data: {
    buildings: []
  },

  computed: {
    buildingCount() {
        return this.buildings.length
    },
    getBuildingRoomsLength(section) {
        return this.buildings.rooms.length
    }
  },

  methods: {    
    addNewRoomToBuilding(buildingId, newRoom) {
        if(newRoom !== undefined) {     this.buildings[parseInt(buildingId)-1].rooms.push(newRoom.title)
      console.log(this.buildings[parseInt(buildingId)-1])
      }
    },
    addNewBuilding() {
        this.buildings.push({
        id: this.buildings.length+1,
        rooms: []
      })
    },

    deleteTodo(todo) {
      this.todos.$remove(todo)
    }
  }
});
```

I am not sure how to make it work. A couple of the things I have noticed is that the room model now is same for all buildings and I have to change it according to the buildingId, however, I can't figure it out yet. Could you please assist me how to do this.

Comment: the code seems to be working. What is the problem?

Comment: FYI you pasted the wrong code

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it. The problem is that if you insert 2 buildings and edit the room input text of one, then the input of the other is also changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your model unique for each item in the buildings array by appending the building id to the end of the name.

So the model name becomes `v-model="newRoom[building.id]"`

And pass the same into your method `addNewRoomToBuilding(building.id, newRoom[building.id])`